# How to get the data from a row that was double-clicked in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs, grid

In an ExtJS grid, I can get the index of the selected data item like this:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect', function(sm, index, rec){
    changeMenuItemInfoArea(menuItemApplication, 'you are on row with index ' + index);
    var row_number_parts = rec.id.split('-'); // rec.id = e.g. "ext-record-1"
    var selected_index = row_number_parts[2] - 1;
    alert(selected_index);
});
```

**But how do I get the index of the selected data item on double click?**

When I do this:

```
listeners: {
    'rowdblclick': function(grid, rowindex, e){
        console.log(...);
    }
}
```

both `grid` and `e` don't seem to have the information I need and `rowindex` isn't useful since if the user resorts a column, then the index of the row double-clicked is not necessarily the index of the dataset which loaded the grid.

## Addendum

Thanks @McStretch, I ultimately solved the issue at hand by putting the `id` in the item list, hiding the id column, then sending the id to the edit page, like this:

```
listeners: {
    'rowdblclick': function(grid, index, rec){
        var id = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().json[0];
        go_to_page('edit_item', 'id=' + id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Index actually refers to the record's index in the store according to the documentation for `cellClick`:

```
function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    // Get the Record, this is the point at which rowIndex references a 
    // record's index in the grid's store.
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);  

    // Get field name
    var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex); 
    var data = record.get(fieldName);
}
```

If this is the case, then you shouldn't have to worry about grid reordering. I think you should get the index/record by using the above methodology in your `'rowdblclick'` listener -- it's much more readable. Test it out and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do this:

```
listeners: {
    'rowdblclick': function(grid, index, rec){
        var row_label = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().id;
        var row_label_parts = row_label.split('-');
        var selected_index = row_label_parts[2] - 1;
        alert(selected_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. The index is correct, even after sort. Sorting is handled at the store level, so the index will match between the store and the grid.